# i don't get ipv6. Why cannot I ping ipv6.google.com?

Tags: linux, ip, routing, ipv6, ping

I am trying to send ipv6 pings from a computer in a LAN. Unfortunately it does not work. It seems that I have an ipv6 address in the LAN, but somehow the `ping -Ieth1 ipv6.google.com` just prints a `connect: Network is unreachable`.

Here is my routing table:

```
    Kernel IPv6 routing table
    Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
    fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
    ::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1429877 lo
    ::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   5     6 lo
    fe80::9a90:96ff:fea4:e451/128  ::                         Un   0   2     5 lo
    ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 8 99924 eth1
    ::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1429877 lo
```

And this is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:90:96:a4:e5:49  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Memory:fb300000-fb37ffff

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:90:96:a4:e4:51  
      inet addr:172.20.33.53  Bcast:172.20.35.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9a90:96ff:fea4:e451/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:946567 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:322832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:144448246 (144.4 MB)  TX bytes:68655794 (68.6 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:fb400000-fb420000

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:463549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:463549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:113166471 (113.1 MB)  TX bytes:113166471 (113.1 MB)
```

Any ideas on what might be the cause and what can I change?

Comment: unless you edit your post, you don't seems to have a public ipv6 adress, this might explain.... fe80:: is local.

Comment: Yup, `fe80::/10` is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address. So until you get a routable IPv6 address (e.g. a tunnel from hurricane electric) you're not going to be able to ping le google.

Comment: I had a similar issue. My ISP doesn't support ipv6. I suggest checking https://test-ipv6.com/ first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have only Link-Local, non routable ipv6 (fe80::/10).

So You have no public routable IPv6.

In this configuration You can make ipv6 connect only to Link-Local addresses in same L2 segment.

Answer (score 2):

To ping using IPv6 you have to use the following command:

> ping6 example.com

But even currently you only have a link-local address so that will not work. You need a IPv6 address that is routable to be able to ping outwards.